# Как правильно конвертировать byte[] в строку (ASCII Рус. символы)?

Tags: c#, кодировка, типы-данных, конвертация, ascii

Например следующий код должен возвращать строку "Г":

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString((new byte[] { 195 }));
```

Но почему возвращается строка: "?".

Как в C# правильно конвертировать массив байт в строку ASCII кодировки с рус. символами?

Comment: ASCII имеет коды 0-127. Так что 195 никак не может быть ASCII. Это может быть какая-то национальная кодировка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) это только 7-бит - никаких значений выше 127. Кодировщик обычно декодирует неизвестные двоичные значения в `?` (хотя это можно изменить с помощью [Decoder Fallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoderfallback.aspx)).

Дальше, чтобы получить букву Г, укажите что вы хотите Кириллицу ( 1251) :

```
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString((new byte[] { 195 })));
    }
}
```

Comment: http://school497.ru/download/u/02/les10/les.html (например) В некоторых источниках указано, что ASCII имеет "вторую половину". Кому верить?) Но: "Международным стандартом является лишь первая половина таблицы, т.е. символы с номерами от 0 (00000000), до 127 (01111111)."

Comment: Контр-пример:  на моем компьютере это английский и французский и для кириллицы я всегда должен указывать кодировку напрямую. Как уточнил @AlexanderPetrov, Default зависит от машины.

Comment: @XXX - это можно задать отдельным вопросом (я плюсану). Чтобы был получен эталонный ответ от гуру, на который потом можно будет ссылаться.

Answer (score 1):

Международным стандартом является лишь первая половина таблицы, т.е. символы с номерами от 0 (00000000), до 127 (01111111)

Альтернативная часть таблицы (русская). Вторая половина кодовой таблицы ASCII, называемая кодовой страницей (128 кодов, начиная с 10000000 и кончая 11111111), может иметь различные варианты, каждый вариант имеет свой номер. 
Кодовая страница в первую очередь используется для размещения национальных алфавитов, отличных от латинского. В русских национальных кодировках в этой части таблицы размещаются символы русского алфавита.

Следующий код работает, как нужно, если указана верная (для нас) локализация на машине:

```
byte[] Test = new byte[] { 195 };
Encoding.Default.GetString(Test);
```

**Но! Использование Default - опасный способ. Сломается на машине, где в данный момент используется другая локализация.**

Comment: Использование `Default` - опасный способ. Сломается на машине, где в данный момент используется другая локаль.